# copy file from a previous version in the svn repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to copy a deleted file from a previous version from the svn repository to my working directory.

I know that the file is present in revision **r***xxx* , because I do `svn log -v` and can see the old revision number associated with the file.

I also do `svn info` to find the repository name which in my case is of the form `svn+ssh://repository`

I then do `svn copy -r xxx svn+ssh://repository name/filename ./filename`

But it complains that `svn: File not found`

Answer (score 11):

By default when you specify the URL of a file in a repository, SVN assumes you're referring to an object **in HEAD**. So your command actually means:

1. locate 'filename' in HEAD
2. trace the history of that file back to revision `xxx`
3. copy the file as it looked then, into the current directory

Of course, this fails at the first step since the file no longer exists in HEAD. You need to explicitly reference the object that *used* to be called `filename` back in revision `xxx`, using what's known as a "peg revision":

```
svn copy -r xxx svn+ssh://repository/filename@xxx ./filename
```

The SVN book has [a more in-depth explanation of peg revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html), if you're feeling brave...

Comment: I don't think you need `-r xxx` in the command above. The peg revision should be just fine.